# Best forum to ask ABBYY questions?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it's here? or elsewhere?  I'm currently posting on mobileread.com, but thought there might be a better community for "power users" (ugh, i hate that term).

Comment: Yeah, everybody at Super User hates that term...

Comment: What exactly is this ABBYY you speak of?

Comment: I reckon he's talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABBYY

Comment: Looks like that would be on-topic, but I have no idea if you'd get any answers...

Answer (score 5):

In general for any specific software package, unless it is ENORMOUSLY HUGE AND POPULAR (see: Word, Excel, etc), you will be better off on the vendor / software specific forums first.